# Return first element of each cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

| Id | Description | Recipient |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | lipsum | 35235 |
| 2 | dolor est | 123, 456, 2432 |
| 3 | Lorem Ipsum | 143243, 34, 2344 |

And I'd like an output like this:

| Id | Description | Recipient | RecipientId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | lipsum | 35235 | 35235 |
| 2 | dolor est | 123, 456, 2432 | 123 |
| 3 | Lorem Ipsum | 143243, 34, 2344 | 143243 |

I need to join a table of recipient data using the recipient IDs. Thankfully, the necessary data will be the same for every recipient in the row, so I only need one ID. I want to return the same data, except with only the first (or even just one) ID for each row in the recipient column.

My current method is like this:

```
SELECT Id,
       Description,
       Recipient,
       MAX(value) as RecipientID
FROM msg 
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(Recipient, ',')
GROUP BY Id, Description, Recipient
```

While this method gives me a single recipient ID that I can then use as a key, it takes quite a long time since the recipient column could have a list of IDs larger than 2k in one cell.

I have tried a REGEX solution to extract the starting set of numbers in front of the delimiter, but I couldn't find a way to do it that wasn't being used as a filter.

It'd be great if SQL Server had a function like MySQL's `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to just get the first ID, but it doesn't.

How could I go about only returning the one element of each recipient cell without having to do a `CROSS APPLY` and aggregating?

Comment: please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad and normalize your table

Comment: You can use `CHARINDEX()` along with `SUBSTRING()` to do this, e.g. `CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',', Recipient) > 0 THEN SUBSTRING(Recipient, 1, CHARINDEX(',', Recipient)-1) ELSE Recipient END` - [Example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=82f61123fac1cdc38debb777bb6541c6). But honestly, just fix your schema. SQL Already has the ideal structure for storing lists of data, they are called tables. Storing delimited lists is almost never the correct solution.

Comment: I agree the schema just needs to be updated, but I am just a lowly data analyst and don't have a say in how the database schema is built. I'm just tasked with making reports that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the base string functions as follows:

```sql
SELECT Id, Description, Recipient,
       SUBSTRING(Receipient + ',', 1, CHARINDEX(',', Recipient + ',') - 1) AS RecipientId
FROM msg;
```

This answer uses a trick by adding a comma to the end of the `Recipient`, so that `CHARINDEX` will always be able to find it.

Comment: I was messing around with ways to handle a recipient with just one value. Your approach of just adding a comma at the end is much nicer than anything I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Required results can be obtained using Case statement as well

```
SELECT  [ID],[Description],[Recipient],SUBSTRING([Recipient],0,case CHARINDEX(',',[Recipient])
      when 0 then len([Recipient])
      else  CHARINDEX(',',[Recipient])
      end) AS RecipientID
  FROM [customer].[dbo].[msg ];
```

In general, it is advised to store the Recipient values in a new table with one to many relationship. Each value is stored in a new row to avoid the use of delimiter. However this query works for your usecase

Answer (score -1):

```
(SELECT TOP value FROM STRING_SPLIT(Recipient, ', ')) as RecipientId
```

Comment: `substring_index` is a [tag:mysql] function, but the question is tagged with [tag:sql-server]

Comment: LIMIT is not in SQL Server either.